# Ready queue simulator - [Error] 'sigINT' and 'sigQUIT' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, scheduler

I have this code for ready queue simulator in C.
When trying to compile and run, it gives the following errors:
**[Error] 'sigINT' undeclared (first use in this function)**
**[Error] 'sigQUIT' undeclared (first use in this function)**

What went wrong here? How can I correct it?

A part of the code is as following;

```
#include "subsystems.h"                 //preprocessor command to integrate subsystems
#include <stdio.h>                  //including basic C commands
#include <pthread.h>                    //including POSIX thread library
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

//GLOBAL CONSTANTS
#define THREADS 4

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
pthread_cond_t queue_not_empty;         //thread condition variable
pthread_mutex_t SIM_LOG;
report_f fr[THREADS];               //CPU data reporting data structures

//BugFixes
#define SIM_SEC 5               //Security constant
int SSEC;                   //Security variable for exitting

//Thread routines
void * job(void * param)            //ready_Q loading function for thread    routine
{
    load_proc((load_proc_t *)param,&queue_not_empty);
    pthread_exit(NULL);         //exit thread execution after reaching EOF in job_file.sys
}

void * cpu(void * param)            //CPU managing function
{
    cpu_data_bind_t * data = (cpu_data_bind_t *)param;   //bind parsed data to given CPU
    ready_Q * rq = data->rq;
    cpu_t *ct = data->cpu;
    printf("CPU:%d functional\n",ct->_id);           //reporting CPU status
    while (1 == 1)
    {
        //store the current CPU statistics to create final report
        fr[ct->_id]._nProc = ct->num_processes;
        fr[ct->_id]._turn =  ct->total_turn_around_time;
        fr[ct->_id]._wait =  ct->total_waiting_time;
        //locking ready_Q
        pthread_mutex_lock(&rq->mutex);
        printf("CPU:%d is idle\n",ct->_id);       //Report CPU status
        SSEC++;                       //Security protocol
        int h = isQFull(rq);                //Check for Queue is Empty
        if (h != 0)
        {
            //make the CPU wait till signal on condition variable is recieved 
            pthread_cond_wait(&queue_not_empty,&rq->mutex);
        }
        attach_process(ct,rq);              //attach given process to CPU
        printf("\n\t--> process %d attached to CPU : %d\n\n",ct->_running->proc_ID,ct->_id);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&rq->mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&SIM_LOG);
        CPU_simulation_service(ct,1,0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&SIM_LOG);
        execute_process(ct);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&SIM_LOG);
        CPU_simulation_service(ct,0,0);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&SIM_LOG);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void sigINT_handle()
{
    if(SSEC > SIM_SEC)
    {
        fr[0]._nProc = 0,fr[0]._turn = 0, fr[0]._wait = 0;
        int i=0;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&SIM_LOG);
        for (i=0;i<THREADS;i++)
        {
            fr[0]._nProc += fr[i]._nProc;
            fr[0]._turn += fr[i]._turn;
            fr[0]._wait += fr[i]._wait;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&SIM_LOG);
        int p = finalReport(&fr[0]);
        printf("\nFinal statistics are reported.\nSimulator exitting...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        errorReport(6);
        signal(SIGINT,sigINT_handle);
    }
}

void sigQUIT_handle()
{
    printf("\n\nExitting simulator..\n\n");
    exit(0);
}

void interactor(int i)
{
    switch(i){
        case 1 : readJobFile();
            printf("press any key to continue..");
            getchar();
            printf("\n");
        break;
        default: 
            printf("\ncontinue simulator operations\n\n");
        break;
    }
}

//Main thread
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //WAITING TILL MAIN IS INITIALIZED...
    signal(sigINT,sigINT_handle);       //signal handler for keyboard INTERRUPT
    signal(sigQUIT,sigQUIT_handle);     //signal handler for keyboard QUIT

    int wait=0,read = -1;           //Initializing waiting time to zero.
    if (argc != 2){
       errorReport(3);          //Invalid usage reporting.
       return -1;
   }
  else{
    if (strcmp(argv[1],"/0")==0)
        wait = 0;       //handling zero special case.
    else if (atoi(argv[1]) == 0){
        errorReport(4);     //invalid argument reporting
        return -1;
    }else
        wait = atoi(argv[1]);   //valid argument setting up.
}
resetSimulation();          //Reset this simulation from previouse simulations.
int k = createJobFile();        //creating the job_file.sys
if (k != 0)
    return -1;          //Exceptional exit. cannot create file.
else
    printf("\n------\n\tSimulator initializing completed\n\tUsage info: keyboard generated interrupt(ctrl + 'C') will quit the simulator\n\tTo exit without reporting, press \" ctrl + \\ \"  \n------\n\n");
SSEC = 0;
        //INITIALIZE COMPLETED

char sx;    //user interaction handling
int ix = 0;
printf("press 1 to view job file log : ");
scanf("%s",&sx);
ix = atoi(&sx); 
interactor(ix); 
getchar();
//to remove user interactions comment out this section

ready_Q rq;             //create ready_Q object.
init_q(&rq);                //Initialize ready_Q object
load_proc_t lpt;
lpt.readyq = &rq;
lpt.w = wait;               //setting up completed for parameter transfer

        //thread setup
pthread_t tid[THREADS];         //creating unique ID's for threads to special purposes.             
pthread_attr_t attr;            //creating a pthread_attr_t object
pthread_attr_init(&attr);       //initializing pthread_attr_t value with defaults.

pthread_mutex_init(&rq.mutex,NULL); //initialize the mutexes
pthread_mutex_init(&SIM_LOG,NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&queue_not_empty,NULL);
//created threads aare joinable.[With respect to POSIX standard]
//by default POSIX pthreads are joinable
pthread_create(&tid[0],&attr,(void *)job,(void *)&lpt); //ready_Q is loaded with processes
//creating CPU instances
cpu_t cpu1 = getInstance(1);
cpu_t cpu2 = getInstance(2);
cpu_t cpu3 = getInstance(3);
//creating data binders for each CPU
cpu_data_bind_t c1_dt;
cpu_data_bind_t c2_dt;
cpu_data_bind_t c3_dt;
//attach data binders for each CPU
c1_dt.cpu = &cpu1;  //CPU 1
c1_dt.rq = &rq;

c2_dt.cpu = &cpu2;  //CPU 2
c2_dt.rq = &rq;

c3_dt.cpu = &cpu3;  //CPU 3
c3_dt.rq = &rq;
//create CPU thread(s)
pthread_create(&tid[1],&attr,(void *)cpu,(void *)&c1_dt);
pthread_create(&tid[2],&attr,(void *)cpu,(void *)&c2_dt);
pthread_create(&tid[3],&attr,(void *)cpu,(void *)&c3_dt);

int i =0;
//suspend main thread till all processing is done.
for (i = 0;i<THREADS;i++)
    pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);

return 0;               //normal exit status is reported.
}
```

Comment: Note: don't use printf inside a signal handler. It is not signal/async safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
signal(sigINT,sigINT_handle);       //signal handler for keyboard INTERRUPT
signal(sigQUIT,sigQUIT_handle);     //signal handler for keyboard QUIT
```

In the above code, the signal names need to be in all caps. That is `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` respectively:

```
signal(SIGINT,sigINT_handle);      
signal(SIGQUIT,sigQUIT_handle);
```

Comment: Okay, but when I changed that to be in all caps, still it says;[Error] 'SIGQUIT' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @Dina1991: normaly it should works, can you share the whole code for we can help you?

Comment: @Dina1991: still missing subsystems.h can you provide it?

Comment: @developer: Actually it's a big set of files, where I won't be able to share the whole program here.. What can I do??